# Inject Windows product key from text file with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, operating-system, key

Question/Problem:
I suck at scripting and am just starting to learn.
I need a batch file to run this executable (c:\get_win8key.exe >c:\key.txt), then take the results of the text file and change the Windows OS key and activate the OS. 
It can not be run via Powreshell, need to use CMD prompt with our automated management tool.

Commands I know:
To pull the key and export to file:
get_win8key.exe >c:\key.txt

To pull the info from the text file:
set /p texte=< file.txt
echo %texte%

To change the product key in command prompt:
slmgr.vbs -ipk [product key ?%texte%?] (not sure about how to place key here)

To activate Windows from command line:
slmgr.vbs /ato

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Reason script is needed:
1: New company workstation deployments moving users from Win7Pro_x64 to Win10Pro_x64.
2: Image to the machines uses the Volume License key for the OS and needs to be changed to the embedded OEM key and activated.

Steps taken:
1: Researched legality of using OEM key with VL imaging rights.
http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=14534
2: Verified PC's have Windows 10 Pro OEM rights and purchased Windows 10 Pro Volume/Open license(s) to gain imaging rights.
3: Found "get_win8key.exe" and am sending the results to a text file. (c:\key.txt).  https://itsolutionsblog.net/3-ways-to-extract-the-windows-8-product-key/
4: Command to pull info from the text file: Can not post link yet
5: Commands to change product key and activate: Can not post link yet

Comment: `slmgr.vbs -ipk [product key %texte%]` should do the trick.

Comment: I created this batch file and the key.txt file is generated, but not populated with the product ket.  When running the get_win8key.exe in CMD it works though.

@echo off
md c:\OEMkey
START /D c:\ get_win8key.exe >c:\OEMkey\key.txt
timeout /T 5
set /p texte=< c:\OEMkey\key.txt
echo %texte%

slmgr.vbs -ipk %texte%

slmgr.vbs /ato

end

Comment: Remove the `start /d` I don't think that's needed

Comment: I got it.  Thank you.  Removing the "Start /d" worked.  I also have to run this batch from an elevated cmd prompt.

Comment: Here is my final script:
md c:\OEMkey
c:\get_win8key.exe >c:\OEMkey\key.txt
timeout /T 1
set /p texte=< c:\OEMkey\key.txt
echo %texte%
slmgr.vbs -ipk %texte%
slmgr.vbs /ato

Comment: Finally got it.  I still had difficulty gettting it to run with elevated privilege.  Downloaded a BAT to EXE converter and then used compatibility tab and set the program to run as Administrator.  worked like a charm.